# Ms teams Mobile and Bot Framework: sending images

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I have a solution that works on Identity and Auth,  The solution runs a WhatsApp Bot that ask the user for images doing specific gestures as part of biometrics for authentication. That works great.

Then We are working with to create support for that bot in Microsoft Teams and other Channels using Azure Bot  Service / Bot Framework , but We're facing troubles because the documentation explicitly says that file exchange between ***ms-teams bots*** and users is **not supported on Mobile**.

Do you know any workaround or OSS component that could remove this blocker?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

[the docs Send and receive files with a bot:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet)

[image]

Comment: I have am not aware of any workaround or solution for this, I've seen it be a pain point for many users/developers.

Comment: This is by design. You can [Send feedback about the Microsoft Teams developer platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback)